Comparing content of hashes and pscustomobject objects
Results for integer and array comparison seem understandable. It does not appear to be comparing the reference (address) of the object. Is it actually comparing the content?
PS C:\> $Int1 = 1
PS C:\> $Int2 = 1
PS C:\> $Int3 = 99
PS C:\> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Int1 -DifferenceObject $Int2)
True
PS C:\> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Int1 -DifferenceObject $Int3)
False
PS C:\> $Array1 = @(1, 2, 3)
PS C:\> $Array2 = @(1, 2, 3)
PS C:\> $Array3 = @(1, 2, 99)
PS C:\> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Array1 -DifferenceObject $Array2)
True
PS C:\> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Array1 -DifferenceObject $Array3)
False

However, comparison of hashes and pscustomobjects does not appear to work the same way. Why are these all comparing as identical?
PS C:\> #How can I compare the contents of the objects?
PS C:\> $Hash1 = @{a=1;b=2}
PS C:\> $Hash2 = @{a=1;b=2}
PS C:\> $Hash3 = @{a=1;b=99}
PS C:\> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Hash1 -DifferenceObject $Hash2)
True
PS C:\> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Hash1 -DifferenceObject $Hash3)
True
PS C:\>
PS C:\> $Obj1 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = "Sam"; Weight = 145}
PS C:\> $Obj2 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = "Sam"; Weight = 145}
PS C:\> $Obj3 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = "Sam"; Weight = 199}
PS C:\> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Obj1 -DifferenceObject $Obj2)
True
PS C:\> $null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Obj1 -DifferenceObject $Obj3)
True



Compare-Object documentation states:

Compare-Object checks for available methods of comparing a whole object. If it can't find a suitable method, it calls the ToString() methods of the input objects and compares the string results.

Diving deeper in the code, we can see the logic used to handle object comparison when the cmdlet is called without -Property, in the  .Compare method from ObjectComparer.
A rough translation of the code in PowerShell, removing irrelevant pieces of code and adding a few verbose lines to understand what is happening in each case, would be:
using namespace System.Management.Automation
using namespace System.Collections

class ObjectCommandComparer : IComparer {
    [cultureinfo] $cultureInfo = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture

    [int] Compare([Object] $first, [Object] $second) {
        if ($first -is [psobject]) {
            Write-Verbose "'`$first' is PSObject, getting BaseObject" -Verbose
            $first = $first.PSObject.BaseObject
        }

        if ($second -is [psobject]) {
            Write-Verbose "'`$second' is PSObject, getting BaseObject" -Verbose
            $second = $second.PSObject.BaseObject
        }

        [int] $result = $null
        $tryCompare = [LanguagePrimitives]::TryCompare(
            $first,
            $second,
            $true,
            $this.cultureInfo,
            [ref] $result)

        if ($tryCompare) {
            Write-Verbose "'LanguagePrimitives.TryCompare' was successful" -Verbose
            return $result
        }

        Write-Verbose "'LanguagePrimitives.TryCompare' failed, wrapping objects and converting ToString" -Verbose

        $firstString = [PSObject]::AsPSObject($first).ToString()
        $secondString = [PSObject]::AsPSObject($second).ToString()

        Write-Verbose "`$firstString : $firstString" -Verbose
        Write-Verbose "`$secondString : $secondString" -Verbose

        return $this.cultureInfo.CompareInfo.Compare(
            $firstString,
            $secondString,
            [System.Globalization.CompareOptions]::None);
    }
}

Using this class, what we can see for the case of hashtables on both sides:
$comparer = [ObjectCommandComparer]::new()
$Hash1 = @{a = 1; b = 2 }
$Hash3 = @{a = 1; b = 99 }
$comparer.Compare($Hash1, $Hash3)

# VERBOSE: 'LanguagePrimitives.TryCompare' failed, wrapping objects and converting ToString
# VERBOSE: $firstString : System.Collections.Hashtable
# VERBOSE: $secondString : System.Collections.Hashtable
# Outputs: 0

So for this case, these objects aren't comparable, Hashtable doesn't implement IComparable so TryCompare fails, then what happens is that both sides are wrapped in PSObject and the .ToString() method is called resulting in the type fully qualified name (System.Collections.Hashtable) and later on the .Compare method from the culture's .CompareInfo is used to compare these 2 strings.
For the case of pscustomobject in both sides we can see something different, as the method checks if they're a psobject to get the .BaseObject, and then .TryCompare succeeds because PSObject does implement IComparable and its .Compare method is just a reference equality. There is many relevant information reading the .Equals implementation (just a bit below .Compare).
$comparer = [ObjectCommandComparer]::new()
$Obj1 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Sam'; Weight = 145 }
$Obj3 = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Sam'; Weight = 199 }
$comparer.Compare($Obj1, $Obj3)

# VERBOSE: '$first' is PSObject, getting BaseObject
# VERBOSE: '$second' is PSObject, getting BaseObject
# VERBOSE: 'LanguagePrimitives.TryCompare' was successful
# Outputs: 0

In both cases, through different code paths, the result is 0, thus the cmdlet doesn't produce any output as it considers that both sides, reference and difference, are equal.

Now to overcome this you could use -Property, for hashtables you can join the keys on both side and get a unique set:
$keys = $Hash1.Keys + $Hash3.Keys | Sort-Object -Unique
Compare-Object $Hash1 $Hash3 -Property $keys

# a  b SideIndicator
# -  - -------------
# 1 99 =>
# 1  2 <=

And for psobjects you can do something similar passing the unique set of .PSObject.Properties.Name:
$props = $Obj1.PSObject.Properties.Name + $Obj2.PSObject.Properties.Name | Sort-Object -Unique
Compare-Object $Obj1 $Obj3 -Property $props

# Name Weight SideIndicator
# ---- ------ -------------
# Sam     199 =>
# Sam     145 <=

Worth noting that these comparison can fail pretty easily (or not) depending on what you want to compare, i.e.:
Compare-Object @{ a = 1 } @{ a = '1' } -Property a

Structurally these hashtables may be the same but their values aren't. If you want to handle these comparisons properly you would need to define your own comparer to handle every possibility.

The first half of this answer only applies to hashtable - [psobject] does implement IComparable, which is why it returns $true: the dummy psco attached as base object is the same. [System.Object]::ReferenceEquals($Obj1.psobject.BaseObject, $Obj3.psobject.BaseObject)

@MathiasR.Jessen thanks I'll update the answer in a bit, still unsure if reference equality is what Compare-Object is doing for psobjects tho, the code is quite complicated

@MathiasR.Jessen hope that update makes more sense

I will accept this as the answer, but I am not totally clear on everything. Work in progress. I found a way around comparing objects for the moment, but it will happen again.

To add to @Mathias' comment: psobject does implement IComparable, but that doesn't come into play here, because it is the .BaseObject property values that are compared. Since, as Mathias notes, all custom objects share a reference to a System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject singleton as their .BaseObject value, comparing any two custom objects by .BaseObject is always true, irrespective of the objects' properties. System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject itself does not implement IComparable, so the equality is determined via a call to .Equals() returning true.


To complement Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer:

Results for integer and array comparison seem understandable. Is it actually comparing the content?


Fundamentally, what Compare-Object compares is:

Each element of input objects that PowerShell considers enumerable in its enumeration contexts, notably in the pipeline; while this is largely based on whether an object's type implements the IEnumerable interface, there are exceptions, notably hashtables (dictionaries), [string], [xml] - see this answer for details.

Otherwise, the input objects themselves.



Independently, if a -Property argument is also given, the specified property/ies are situationally accessed on each element of the enumerable input objects / the input objects themselves, as appropriate.



Thus, the question boils down to the specific method used to compare the (ultimately) individual objects:

It follows from the above that both hashtables (dictionaries) - due to not being considered enumerables by PowerShell - and [pscustomobject]s - due to fundamentally not implementing IEnumerable - are considered individual objects.



Why are these all comparing as identical? [[hashtable] and [pscustomobject] instances]


The - quite complex - general comparison rules are detailed in the bottom section of this answer.

It follows that for the types at hand, specifically, the comparison rules are:

[hashtable] (IDictionary):

This type / interface does not implement IComparable, so the latter interface cannot be consulted.

Therefore, its instances are compared via the .Equals() method, which performs reference-equality testing, and therefore only returns true for two references that reference the very same instance.

Since in your example you're comparing two distinct instances - whether or not they happen to contains the same key-value pairs - .Equals() returns false, which causes Compare-Object to fall back to string comparison.

Since at least [hashtable] instances inherit the default .ToString() implementation - which simply returns the full type name, System.Collections.Hashtable - to Compare-Object any two distinct instances - perhaps surprisingly - are therefore considered equal.



[pscustomobject] (aka [psobject]):

While [pscustomobject] == [psobject] itself implements IComparable, this is not relevant in this case, because Compare-Object compares such instances by the value of their .BaseObject property.

In the case of true custom objects - i.e. [pscustomobject] == [psobject] instances that do not wrap another .NET instance and simply act as ad hoc "property bags" via instance-level ETS members - all such instances reference the very same placeholder singleton of type System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject in their .BaseObject property.


Therefore, in the context of Compare-Object, any two custom objects by definition compare as equal, irrespective of their properties, as the following example, expressed in terms of an -eq operation, demonstrates:
# !! -> $true, for any two (true) [pscustomobject] instances.
([pscustomobject] @{ one = 1 }).psobject.BaseObject -eq ([pscustomobject] @{ two = 2 }).psobject.BaseObject


That is, for two distinct custom-object instances, comparing them via  .Equals() on their .BaseObject value[1] always returns $true (because reference equality is tested for, and both values indeed reference the very same object), and it is a return value of $true that Compare-Object honors as-is, without falling back to string comparison.


Note that both of the above Compare-Object behaviors are inconsistent with using the -eq operator on two distinct instances of these types: using -eq performs a reference equality test (given that both types are .NET reference types, though, strictly speaking, [psobject] has explicit rather than inherited logic that amounts to this behavior), so that any two distinct instances return $false, irrespective of their content; e.g.,
([pscustomobject] @{ one = 1 }) -eq ([pscustomobject] @{ one = 1 }) yields $false.







[1] Note the need for .psobject.BaseObject to access the .BaseObject property, which is something that's only necessary in PowerShell code, where PowerShell presents a hybrid view of a custom object: to Get-Member and .GetType(), a custom object self-reports as System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject, i.e. as the type of the placeholder singleton stored in its .BaseObject property, even though it is technically of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject (which is what both [pscustomobject] and [psobject] are short for), as evidenced by -is [psobject] - somewhat paradoxically - also being true. The latter's .BaseObject property is - sensibly - hidden by default (alongside [psobject]'s other properties and methods) when a custom object is accessed, given that you only want to see the explicitly added instance-level ETS properties (e.g., [pscustomobject] @{} | Get-Member -Type Properties has no output). The intrinsic .psobject property is therefore needed to gain access to the true [psobject] members.

Thanks, @Santiago: there were to problems that are now corrected: (a)  typos (I'd forgotten the @ before { ... }) and (b) you actually need .psobject.BaseObject  in order to access the .BaseObject value (the System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject singleton). In C# code, just .BaseObject is enough.

@Santiago: I now see that you had the .psobject.BaseObject part correct in your answer all along - I missed it, because I was debugging PowerShell's source code. Anyway, I can confirm that IComparable is not in the picture and neither is .ToString() (for custom objects), so I suggest fixing that part of your answer (which already had my +1).

P.S., @Santiago: For me the final piece of the puzzle with respect to the System.Management.Automation.PSObject / System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject confusion in PowerShell code just fell into place, which I've (hopefully correctly) just summarized in a footnote to the answer.

Code is quite a mess but if I'm reading it correctly the key is here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/da1ca4a7266e2c9e43f96a38aeea8092ace71cca/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/ObjectCommandComparer.cs#L160-L180, if left and right are initialized with no selected properties it just returns 0 (both equal) ?

or actually just a bit below that, using LanguagePrimitives.TryCompare on both .BaseObject if both sides are PSObject which would always be 0

@SantiagoSquarzon: Yes; specifically, this point is reached: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/fc68b61d2f2c00c34f1babcec3289653e90312b0/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L964 Note that it's fundamentally curious that .TryCompare() is called, even though Compare-Object - in spite of its name - doesn't need ordering, just  equality tests. There are two bugs associated with this: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12498 and https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/23805

yeah, no idea but they should be using LanguagePrimitives.Equals here I believe. i'll update my answer later
